# How to use font base64 in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, fonts, base64

I want create an application in visual basic, i want a custom font but that's a ttf file, I can use file but I have app_name.exe and Akashi.ttf (my font) in "/bin"

```
Dim Akashi As PrivateFontCollection = New PrivateFontCollection
Akashi.AddFontFile("Akashi.ttf")
FrameWindow.Font = New Font(Akashi.Families(0), 8)
```

I want to use the base64 encoding to use this font without file...

Please help me
(sorry for my english, i'm french)

Comment: Base64 is a way to encode binary data as a string.  What that has to do with a font is *very* hard to guess.  If you want to embed the font file as a resource then you'll have to use the AddMemoryFont() method instead.  Beware that it is hard to use correctly, google for sample code.

Comment: I found a solution :

Comment: @Phoenix - Please post your solution as an answer and then accept it so it can help others.

Comment: Just write a file content font etc... It's temporal...

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this will work, but try putting your font in the application resources. Right-click your project in the solution explorer and press "Properties", then go to the "Resources" tab and drag your font there.

Then you'll just simply do:

```
Dim Akashi As PrivateFontCollection = New PrivateFontCollection
Akashi.AddFontFile(My.Resources.Akashi)
FrameWindow.Font = New Font(Akashi.Families(0), 8)
```

Comment: That doesn't work... I tried this before, i found, I write a tmp file where my font is contained...